# Phpmailer Multiple Mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to save multiple tasks and send multiple emails for each user. My code is shortly like this:

```
<?php
//Save All
foreach($_POST['decode'] as $dcode){

$sec = mysql_query("SELECT owner,mcode FROM members WHERE mcode='$dcode' ORDER BY id ASC");
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($sec)){$mcode=$list[mcode];$owner=$list[owner];}        

if (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tasks (tcode,adder,tdt,title,mcode,subject)
values ('$tcode','$adder','$tdt','$title','$mcode','$subject')")){

        echo $owner.' done.<br>';header ("refresh: 5; url=members.php");

        //Send info
        include("scripts/class.phpmailer.php");

        //To who
        $sec = mysql_query("SELECT name,em FROM members WHERE mcode='$mcode' ORDER BY id ASC");
        while($list = mysql_fetch_array($sec)){$name = $list[name];$em = $list[em];}
        //Sender
        $sec = mysql_query("SELECT owner FROM members WHERE mcode='$owner' ORDER BY id ASC");
        while($list = mysql_fetch_array($sec)){$owner = $list[owner];}

        $mail= new PHPMailer();
        $mail->AddAddress($em , $name);
        $mail->Subject=$owner."has send mail";
        $mail->Body="content";
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host="host.host.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->Username="username";
        $mail->Password="pass";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From="sendermail";
        $mail->FromName="Sender";
        $mail->Port="587";
        $done=$mail->Send();

        // Check Mail
        if(!$done){echo "Error! Mail not send";}else{echo "Mail send";}         

}else{echo "Not Saved";}    
}//Save All
?>
```

It saves the tasks. And sends a single mail. But i cant send multiple emails for each task.

**Phpmailer sends error: Cannot declare class**
I've tried this way for that error:

```
if(class_exists('PHPMailer') != true){$mail= new PHPMailer();}
```

**And it says Call to a member function AddAddress()**
And ive tried this way:

```
$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

And i think im putting the codes to wrong areas. Can u please help me to fix this.
I've searched "stack" and tried a few methods also. But they doesnt work on mine.
I think thats about the foreach command.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, and you have sql injection issues in your code. These are outside the realm of the answer you seek, but do please correct them before using this. Use mysqli/PDO instead

Comment: @Zarazthuztra thanks for the great warning man. But im new at coding. Can u send me a source for the explanations.

Comment: Absolutely dude! Here's the docs on mysqli http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. It can be used procedurally, just like mysql_*, or in an object oriented fashion (which I recommend learning anyway). So it's really not much different than what you're used to, just some minor tweaks. As for SQL injection, just use mysqli prepared statements. Drop me a line if you have questions about them, but the docs are pretty good.

Comment: Sorry to double comment, but you're using the include construct inside a loop, which is just going to keep including the same code. I recommend using that include outside your for loop, and using include_once instead :)

Comment: @Zarazthuztra hmm thanks for the include info. And the source made my eyes open :D Its too prof. for me for now :) I'll try to upgrade my codes to mysqli by time. Thanks for the good infos again :)

Comment: Also SQL injections, at least use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir thanks but intead of which code or where must be?

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir If he moves over to mysqli, he can use prepared statements, which are safer than relying on escape string alone, plus parameter bindings.

OP: Just a little more practice and all will become clear :)

Comment: Yes PDO or ActiveRecord is what has to be used here.

Comment: @Zarathuztra hi man. can u explain how mysql_i or PDO works at this code please: `$do = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_work"));`

I'm trying to understand the schema. So i think that can be easy in a basic code

Comment: @MadGemini Just checkout the docs on mysqli and I think you'll find that the syntax is almost exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

```
//Sender
$sec = mysql_query("SELECT owner FROM members WHERE mcode='$owner' ORDER BY id ASC");
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($sec))
{
    $owner = $list[owner];
}

$mail= new PHPMailer();
$mail->Body="content";
$mail->Subject=$owner."has send mail";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host="host.host.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->Username="username";
$mail->Password="pass";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From="sendermail";
$mail->FromName="Sender";
$mail->Port="587";

//To who
$sec = mysql_query("SELECT name,em FROM members WHERE mcode='$mcode' ORDER BY id ASC");
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($sec))
{
    $email = $list['em'];
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Send();
}
```

Comment: While I do believe this answer is correct, why not enhance it and explain why it works and what OP was doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are creating instance in a loop. Creating instance in a loop is like sending different mail each time.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir how must i fill in the "for" looper?

Comment: while($list = mysql_fetch_array($sec)){$name = $list[name];$em = $list[em];} This is foor loop for you. since you need name and email in for loop.

Comment: Fetch "Sender" first and then "To who", use "To who"while loop instead of for, and use $em as $email

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function ClearAddresses() on a non-object

Comment: Thanks. Now i have this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::IsSMTP()
at here $mail->IsSMTP();

Comment: May be your class does not have this function definition check this link or download another from here. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial